# Raspberry Pi - How to do other things while preview is running?

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I am currently writing a script that creates a GUI (writing it with Tkinter) that does a bunch of things. Among them is the ability to start previewing with the camera, and then being able to move this motor forwards and backwards at will. Unfortunately, the preview blocks me from doing anything else with the GUI as it is running, is there any way around it? In my ideal world, you can press the GUI buttons to move the motor forward and backward with the preview running in the background and providing you with active feedback. Here is some of my code:

```
def motorOut():
    backwards(int(delayf) / 1000.0, int(stepsf))
    setStep(0,0,0,0)

def motorIn():
    forward(int(delayb) / 1000.0, int(stepsb))
    setStep(0,0,0,0)

def cameraPreview():

    camera.start_preview(fullscreen=False, window = (400, 240, 400, 240))
    sleep(20)
    camera.stop_preview()
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely not the preview that is blocking your program, but using `sleep(20)`.

Whilst the 'sleep' is occurring, nothing else can process. This causes the block you are noticing. You could fix this by removing that line, and instead binding the `camera.stop_preview()` to an event (such as a key press). This could look like:

```
root.bind("<space>", lambda e: camera.stop_preview())
```

Where `root` is what you define as your access to `Tk()`. `lambda e:` specifies an inline function expression, where `e` is the event object passed.

Comment: It works! For the most part... I put that code in instead of the sleep and now it lets me click other buttons, but I can't exit the preview now. It's not a huge issue since it's just a little square in the bottom right of my screen, but how do I define root as my access to Tk() to solve this? Sorry about the question I'm kind of a beginner programmer.

Comment: When using Tkinter, you would define `root = Tk()` nearly all of the time at the start of your program, to use to reference various Tk functions/methods, such as `bind`. Glad this helped!

Comment: ah, of course! I had called it win, so I just replaced root with win and it worked like a charm. Thank you so so much!